# Wordpress: make an ACF field not required if conditional logic hides it

Tags: wordpress, conditional-statements, advanced-custom-fields, required

In my WordPress system I use the latest version of the ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) plugin, version 4.4.11. I have an extra text field which shows or hides in the UI based on a user selection. This can be accomplished using the conditional logic in ACF and it works fine. But I can either set this extra field to required or not, and my target is to make it only be required if it shows, not if it is hidden. I guess this can't be set using the plugin panel. Can anyone tell me how to get this working correctly? I haven't found any solution so far. Thanks for your support!

Comment: It is possible acf is having settings for this while you create a custom field.

Comment: @AkshayShah could you please tell me how? I can't seem to find the settings for that ...